# dudas sobre las llamadas a los constructores metodo swap

Tags: c++11

En mi main tengo las siguientes instrucciones:

```
message("std::swap");
std::swap(*a, *b);
```

La clase strc tiene el siguiente atributo:

```
    Char * data;
```

A continuacion os pongo los constructores que usa swap por debajo.

```
strc::strc(strc && o) {
    data = std::move(o.data);
    o.data = nullptr;
    msg("move ctor");
}

strc::~strc() {
     msg("dtor");
     delete[] data;
}

strc & strc::operator = (strc o) {
     std::cout<<o.data;
     swap(o);
     msg("copy and swap =");
     return *this;
 }

 const char * strc::value() const {
     return data;
 }

 strc::operator const char * () const {
    return value();
 }

 void strc::swap(strc & o) {
    std::swap(this->data, o.data);
 }
```

Esta es la la salida para ver las llamadas que se hacen a los constructores cuando llamó a swap.

```
 std::swap
 strc: move ctor (one)
 strc: move ctor (two)
 strc: copy and swap = (two)
 strc: dtor
 strc: move ctor (one)
 strc: copy and swap = (one)
 strc: dtor
 strc: dtor
```

Alguien me podría explicar el procedimiento interno que siguen. En move ctor, entiendo que me devuelve una instancia donde su "data" es el string de a y de b en las respectivas llamadas, pero cuando el constructor = llama a  swap(strc & o) no se donde se esta guardando data, si en principio ya lo habia guardado en la instancia en el move constructor.Me pierdo . Si alguien me lo puede explicar todo el proceso de std::swap(*a, *b) y que hace consigue con cada llamada a los constructores.

Le he puesto en modo debug, veo que se mueve

```
   #endif
    {
       // concept requirements
        __glibcxx_function_requires(_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>)

        _Tp __tmp = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__a);
        __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
        __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
     }

  template<typename _Tp>
      constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
      move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
        { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
```

Pero me pierdo al tratar de seguirlo porque crea punteros _t  y direcciones que no logro comprender.

Saludos

Comment: A ver si te he entendido bien; ¿ estás preguntando porqué ` void strc::swap(strc & o) { std::swap(this->data, o.data); }`  no muestra ninguna salida ?

Comment: He reeditado la pregunta para que este más claro. Realmente quiero que alguien me explique que se consigue o que hace swap(*,*) por debajo y que se consigue con cada llamada a los constructores. Vamos el algoritmo de swap(*,*)

Comment: No tiene mucho misterio: `void swap( T &a, T &b ) { T tmp( std::move( a ); a = std::move( b ); b = std::move( tmp ); }` Y tus mensajes no lo dejan claro porque no lo estás haciendo bien: `strc::operator = (strc o)`: Fíjate que pasas el objeto **por valor**, se crea un temporal extra.

Comment: Ah, vale, que te refieres a **tu `strc::swap( )`** Ahora ya si :-)

Comment: Ah, pues no, que te refieres al `std::swap( )` ... lo siento, pero sigo sin entenderte ... los fines de semana son malos para estas cosas :-)

Comment: El swap(*a,*b) recibe dos punteros y lo q hace es crear objetos y cambiar punteros. a es un puntero a un objeto strc, que tiene como atributo un char* data. Es un ejemplo que vi en un manual, pero esa parte no lo detalla. Y veo que se llama al constructor move: que creo que obtiene data=strc::move(o.data) que es un atributo de la clase strc que es un puntero char*. Y pone la referencia o.data=null. Después llama a operator = y ya me pierdo aquí. Porque este método recibe o por copia y no se si es el que tiene o.data=null ... me lío y no se erguir low hace.